# Как переименовать сетевой ресурс?

Tags: windows, lan, доступ

Бодрого всем дня.
Есть вопрос.
Как переименовать сетевой ресурс?Т.е. я его подключаю, и он у юзеров видется как вот так:

[image]

Вот на показанном примере, это Docs, у меня Shared.
Вопрос - Реализована ли в Windows XP возможность переименования Общего ресурса?
Или только бегать(заходить) по всем клиентским машинам и вручную переименовывать на каждом?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помог реестр, только опять на клиентском ПК.
Но всё же.
Раз ресурс можно переименовать на клиенте, значит это где-то храниться в ПК клиента, а значит в реестре.
Создал cmd c reg add + всё остальное и посылаю его юзерам.
Всё!
Теперь ресурс можно переименовывать хоть 10 раз без переподключения и выглядит он как просто название и буква диска, без какой-либо доп информации.Спасибо MicroSoft TechNet.

---

cmd выглядит у меня примерно так:

```
@echo offnet use [буква_диска]: \\[имя_пк_или_ip_адрес]\[имя_ресурса] persistent:yesreg add HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MountPoints2\##[имя_пк_или_ip_адрес]#[имя_ресурса] /v _LabelFromReg /t REG_SZ /d "[названия_ресурса_в_DOS_кодировке]" /f
```

Comment: Ну мог бы и ссыль кинуть - вдруг людям потребуется

Answer (score 0):

Отменяете общий доступ, затем назначаете его заново и указываете любое имя.

Comment: Я так понимаю это простое переименование каталога на файловом сервере вы предлагаете.  Но если я переименую таким путём, то все сетевые подключения отвалятся + отвалятся все ярлыки установленные юзерами на своих рабочих станциях.

Comment: Да, ссылки (ярлыки) на него будут неактивны - это в любом случае.  Однако, можно изменить имя ресурса в сети без изменения имени папки:  1) вкладка "Доступ", кнопка "новый общий ресурс" - жмем;  2) выбираем параметры ресурса и ОК;  3) выбираем на вклад "доступ" прежнее имя ресурса и жмем появившуюся кнопу "удалить общ ресурс".  .  НО можно и не удалять, тогда будет ДВА сетевых имени, ведущих к одной папке. Будет работать старый ярлык, новые - но это не очень хороший выход из положения.